# How to connect a mobile app to IBM Blockchain

Tags: mobile, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to link a mobile app to the IBM Blockchain network, and I do not see any options for mobile app linking.
Should I use the connection profile?

Comment: Can you specify which kind of mobile app you wanna connect and where exactly you searched for options?

Comment: I am trying to connect iOS and android native apps, and I searched for options in IBM code patterns and developer guides

Answer (score 0):

The IBP connection profile provides minimal information for an application to use the discovery service to discover your IBP Blockchain network. This connection profile is in a format that can be consumed easily by the gateway apis found in the fabric node sdk and fabric java sdk that you could use to write a client application or a client server that could process requests on behalf of a mobile app for example

Comment: So could I use a node.js server to connect the app to the blockchain network?

Comment: Yes you can do it that way.

Comment: Hi I still do not understand how do I communicate with the blockchain network via the node.js server. Would I have to use a direct command like this(let server = "http://localhost:3000") to connect? However, this would only allow data transfer between UI and node, and how would I have communication directly to the blockchain from the UI?